# can i get a large image with low pixels?

Tags: java-me

i want to store an image in mobile application. the image is a map. because a map would be big one, so i could not get an image with low pixels and large size in a normal mobile. can you give me some idea so that i can use an image approx 220 x 170 pixels with more than the screen size (a map where one could navigate by scrolling up-down-right-left.)

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking about how to implement a tiling solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "low pixels and large size" exactly? Can you give a more detailed description? I can't understand what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: 220x170x4 8-bit layers is "only" 150KB of memory. A 256-color palette could be used to reduce that to 37KB. Nothing for any but the most modest phones these days but since the question is tagged as "java-me" ... hardest thing is likely to get it to play nice with whatever phone/Java API is exposed (I don't use Java ME)